# Windows Explorer Sorting Files

Tags: windows, sorting, explorer

I got a question that i just can't figure out and hopefully someone can help me out with it.
It is about file sorting in the windows explorer.
I got as example a list of files like this:

```
File1 (Extra text)
File1 (Some More)
File1
File2 (Extra text)
File2
File3 (Extra text)
File3 (Random text)
File3
```

But i want it to be sorted like this:

```
File1
File1 (Extra text)
File1 (Some More)
File2
File2 (Extra text)
File3
File3 (Extra text)
File3 (Random text)
```

Is there something that can be done about this without renaming files?
I still want them to be in the Alfabetical sorting, but certain files are identical only they have sometimes a extra part of text behind them between "( )"

Edit: As requested a example screenshot:
[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: in my explorer when i sort for "Name" it's as you want.

Comment: Weird for me it isn't...
Well hopefully someone has a idea

Comment: can you add a windows explorer screenshot in the question? 
what version of windows do you have?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...
I am running Windows 10 Pro (Latest version as far as i know)
Screenshot will be attached in a few minutes :)

Comment: you can try to turn off the display of file extensions. Can you take a screenshot of the whole explorer window and with the examples you made?